# Multiple calendars in Windows

Tags: windows-7, calendar

Windows 7 allows users to display multiple clocks (for different time zones). Is there a way to have multiple calendars there too? For example, can I display both Gregorian and Islamic (Hijri) calendars side-by-side?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 doesn't support this feature unfortunately. You'll probably have more luck looking for calendar gadgets. For what it's worth, Google Calendar has a wide variety of [calendars](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37098?hl=en) you can subscribe to, albeit being a web app, rather than a desktop app.